# How to order graph's nodes such that the distance between two adjacent nodes is minimal

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, graph

I was wondering if this problem is known in graph theory:
I have an undirected graph with no weights G=(V,A) and I want to place the nodes of this graph in a string so that directed nodes are placed as much close as possible. So for example:

Given  this graph:

```
a,b;a,d;b,e;c,f;c,h;f,h;e,g;e,h.
```

where arcs are separated by ';'

I need to get to this solution:
a,b,d,e,g,h,c,f=2
where 2 is the maximum distance in the string a,b,d,e,g,h,c,f between two directed nodes.

**Formally:**

- let d(v,u) be the distance between two nodes according to the graph.
- Find an order v<sub>1,</sub>,v<sub>2,</sub>,v<sub>n,</sub>, such that max{d(v<sub>i,</sub>,v<sub>i+1,</sub>) } is minimal

Comment: I need to put all the nodes of the graph in that string and check the distance (in the string) between every two nodes connected by a direct arc. The maximum distance gives the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems **you are facing a variation of the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)**.

In this problem, given a graph - you are looking for a path that go through all vertices without repeating any node twice.

Note that a hamiltonian path is a perfect solution to your problem, and thus if your problem can be solved efficiently - so does the hamiltonoan path problem.

Unfortunately, there is no known polynomial solution for the hamiltonian path problem, and the problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete) (so the general belief is such a (efficient) solution does not exist).

A brute force solution will be O(n!) - check all possible permutations, and choose the optimal one. This can be optimized using [branch and bound techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).